# Byte Extraction , which is the better method of the two

Tags: cpu-word, byte

I have a query on selection of method to extract a byte from the word. My word is currently unsigned. It is simply collection of 32 bits.(1s and 0s). Both the follwing script I implement returns me same result. I wonder which is a better option to select.

```
Bytes0=(UINT8)((Word>>00 & 0x0000FF);
Bytes1=(UINT8)(Word>>08  & 0x0000FF);
Bytes2=(UINT8)(Word>>16  & 0x0000FF);
Bytes3=(UINT8)(Word>>24  & 0x0000FF);

or
Bytes0=(UINT8)((Word>>00);
Bytes1=(UINT8)(Word>>08 );
Bytes2=(UINT8)(Word>>16 );
Bytes3=(UINT8)(Word>>24 );
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks
DSP Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast to UINT8 is discarding all the bytes except for the lowest one. So in the first case, you convert the upper bytes to 0 and then discard them; in the second you simply discard them.  The second option is clearly more efficient, assuming you are assigning to a UINT8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question, if it is signed instead of unsigned, will it have any impact?

Comment: It changes how the bits are filled by the >> operator. But since those bits are discarded by the cast, the end result should be the same.